# AS3 FlashCS6 Vector of bitmapData

Tags: actionscript-3

I want make all things as a `Sprite` because I heard that's a good idea till it's not pro animated. I made it this way:

//Assets.as

```
[Embed(source = "../lib/Textures/Game/GameBackground.jpg")] public static const GameBackground:Class;
```

then I have class when I want to use this:

//Game.as

```
private var pic:Bitmap = new Assets.GameBackground();
private var DATA:Vector.<BitmapData> = new Vector.<BitmapData>([pic.bitmapData]);
private var backgroundImg:Bitmap = new Bitmap(new BitmapData(1, 1));    

public function Game(){
    addChild(backgroundImg);
    backgroundImg.bitmapData = DATA[0];
}
```

I know it's useless when I have only one bitmap to use vector, but later gonna have spritesheets or buttons with two bitmaps. What's more I want to store those Vectors in Asstets.as
And have problem even with trying to create them in class where i want it to use, cause:

1. trying: this way: `data:Vector.<BitmapData> = new Vector.<BitmapData>([pic]);`
   Receiving error: The index 0 is out of range 0.
2. trying: this way: `data:Vector.<BitmapData> = new Vector.<BitmapData>[pic];`
   Receiving: Instantiation attempted on a non-constructor. Which is pretty obvious i think.

when I'm using only `pic:Bitmap` and `backgroundImg.bitmapData = pic.bitmapData` it works, but I don't want it this way. Need to use vector when have a lot more of bitmaps for one sprite. Or even one world. What's more, want to create those vectors inside Assets.as class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you create a new Vector instance, the only argument it accepts (optionally) is the length of the Vector (how many elements you'll have).

```
new Vector:<BitmapData>(5)
```

That would tell the vector that it will have 5 elements.  unlike array you can't pass in elements in the constructor.  It you omit the parameter, it makes the length dynamic so it can grow/shrink as needed.

What you need to do is the following:

```
data:Vector.<BitmapData> = new Vector:<BitmapData>();
data.push(pic.bitmapData);
```

More on creating vectors
http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7ee5.html#WSB1F41227-C612-4f33-A00E-CE84C1913E1C

Answer (score 0):

ur idea works pretty nice =O

I did it for some global images and works pretty well:

```
[Embed(source="greenled.png")] private static const greenled:Class;
[Embed(source="yellowled.png")] private static const yellowled:Class;
[Embed(source="redled.png")] private static const redled:Class;
public static const SIGN:Vector.<Class> = Vector.<Class>([greenled,yellowled,redled]);
```